# Wordpress Portfolio showing all items but i want it to show as per the category

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories, portfolio

Hello i have one site http://anujtradingco.com/ i have created 2 pages with name rugs and bathmats and they have template as 3 col portfolio and but when eva i m clicking any of the both pages they showing whole portfolio i.e. it showing bathmats and rugs together in both pages.

mainly this line getting the post but i want to put a filter in it so kindly help me out and this is the line which getting the all post

```
query_posts("post_type=portfolio&paged=".get_query_var('paged'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass category-id (cat=3) if using categories such as:

```
query_posts("post_type=portfolio&cat=3&paged=".get_query_var('paged'));
```

If there are custom taxonomies (for ex: taxonomies name is 'actor') the syntax would be such as:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'movie',
    'actor'    => 'Bruce Campbell, Chuck Norris',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

For more you can visit:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Although **[WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)** is recommended approach instead of query_posts